# How to grab S3 Bucket Object/Key by passing the S3 bucket name as parameter using perl?

Tags: perl, amazon-s3

Is it possible to retrieve S3 Bucket Object/Key by passing the S3 bucket name as parameter using Perl?

Comment: Have you tried something using CPAN modules like https://metacpan.org/pod/AWS::S3::Bucket?

Answer (score 1):

The standard (huge!) way to interact with AWS from Perl is by using [Paws](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws).

In fact, the examples for that distribution include one called `s3-listall.pl` which is very much like what you want, I think.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
 
use v5.10;
use Paws;
 
my $bucket = $ARGV[0] or die "Usage $0 bucket\n";
 
my $s3 = Paws->service('S3', region => 'eu-west-1');
 
my $res = $s3->ListAllObjects(
  Bucket => $bucket
);
 
foreach my $object (@{ $res->Contents }) {
  say $object->Key;
}
```